# PEG.js grammar for parsing CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, css, parsing, grammar, peg.js

I have a library that's parsing some expressions, part of which is a CSS selector.  More accurately, it's a jQuery-compatible selector.  The selector itself is opaque to my library - I don't need to pick it apart, and I don't need to verify that tag and attribute names are valid HTML, or that its pseudo-selectors exist in the current spec.  For now, I just need it to match all syntactically valid CSS selectors and not match the rest of the expression, which is delimited by characters that would not be valid in a selector unless escaped or put in a string in an attribute selector.  I would use a `RegExp` and `split` the string if CSS had no escapes or quoted values, but it started looking write-only really fast.

Does this PEG.js grammar cover all the other edge cases as defined by the CSS standard and jQuery documentation?  Could it be more readable?  Better in some other way?

```
{
/* 
 * glom the array contents returned by the parser
 * into a string recursively.
 */
function collapse(stuff) {
    if (typeof stuff === "string") {
        return stuff;
    } else if (stuff instanceof Array) {
        return stuff.reduce(function (a, item) {
            return a.concat(collapse(item));
        }, "")
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

/*
 * Replace superfluous white space with a single space.
 */
function trimWs(present) {
    if (present) {
        if (present instanceof Array) {
            return !!present.length ? " " : "";
        } else {
            return " ";
        }
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

}

start = jqSelector

ws "white space" = 
    whites:(" " / "\r" / "\n" / "\t" / "\f")+
{ return collapse(whites); }

iws "ignored white space" = ws? { return ""; }
cws "collapsed white space" = ws:ws { return trimWs(ws); }

jqSelector "jquery-compatible selector" =
    element:(tagIdClassSelector / cssFunctional / cssAttrExpr)+
    more:(iws [\+>~,] iws jqSelector / cws jqSelector)?
  { return collapse([element, more]); }


tagIdClassSelector "tag, id, or class selector" =
    [#\.]? cssIdentifier / "*"

cssIdentifier "CSS identifier" = 
    start:cssIdStart rest:cssIdChar* 
{
    return collapse([start, rest]);
}

cssIdStart "start of CSS identifier" =
    [a-zA-Z_]
  / escapedChar
  / "-" ([a-zA-Z_] / escapedChar)

cssIdChar "rest of CSS identifier" =
    [-a-zA-Z0-9_] / escapedChar

escapedChar "escape sequence" =
    "\\" (escapedUnicode / .)

escapedUnicode "1-6 hexadecimal digits (unicode escape)" = 
    d0:hexd (d1:hexd (d2:hexd (d3:hexd (d4:hexd d5:hexd?)?)?)?)?
{
    return [d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5].join("");
}
hexd "hexadecimal digit" =
    [0-9a-fA-F]

cssFunctional "pseudo-selector or functional selector" =
    ":" cssIdentifier ( "(" cssArg ")" )?

cssAttrExpr "attribute selector" =
    "[" cssIdentifier (
        [|~\*^$]? "=" (cssIdentifier / quotedString)
    )? "]"

quotedString "quoted string" = 
    "'" (escapedChar / [^\'])* "'"
  / '"' (escapedChar / [^\"])* '"'

cssArg "functional selector argument" = 
    anpbOddEven / uint / jqSelector

anpbOddEven "'an+b' expression, 'odd',  'even', or integer" = 
    [-\+]? uint? [nN] (ws* [-\+] ws* uint)? 
  / [-\+] uint 
  / "even"
  / "odd"

uint "unsigned integer" = [1-9][0-9]* / "0"
```

Compiled JS parser & minimal interactive tester is here: http://jsfiddle.net/np6BD/

**UPDATE**

Incorporating suggestions regarding the JS:

```
{
/* 
 * glom the array contents returned by the parser
 * into a string recursively.
 * Elses aren't logically necessary to perform this function,
 * but if I use code folding in my IDE, it still looks like it
 * does what it does if I include the elses.
 * Changed name from "collapse" to prevent confusion about
 * the other sense of the word in the cws token.
 * Changed reduce/concat to map/join.
 */
function serialize(stuff) {
    if (typeof stuff === "string") {
        return stuff;
    } else if (stuff instanceof Array) {
        return stuff.map(serialize).join("");
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

/*
 * Replace superfluous white space with a single space.
 * Function moved to the cws token
 */
}

start = jqSelector

ws "white space" = 
    whites:(" " / "\r" / "\n" / "\t" / "\f")+
{ return serialize(whites); }

iws "ignored white space" = ws? { return ""; }
cws "collapsed white space" = ws:ws 
{ 
    if (ws) {
        if (ws instanceof Array) {
            return !!ws.length ? " " : "";
        } else {
            return " ";
        }
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

jqSelector "jquery-compatible selector" =
    element:(tagIdClassSelector / cssFunctional / cssAttrExpr)+
    more:(iws [\+>~,] iws jqSelector / cws jqSelector)?
{
    return serialize([element, more]);
}


tagIdClassSelector "tag, id, or class selector" =
    [#\.]? cssIdentifier / "*"

cssIdentifier "CSS identifier" = 
    start:cssIdStart rest:cssIdChar* 
{
    return serialize([start, rest]);
}

cssIdStart "start of CSS identifier" =
    [a-zA-Z_]
  / escapedChar
  / "-" ([a-zA-Z_] / escapedChar)

cssIdChar "rest of CSS identifier" =
    [-a-zA-Z0-9_] / escapedChar

escapedChar "escape sequence" =
    "\\" (escapedUnicode / .)

escapedUnicode "1-6 hexadecimal digits (unicode escape)" = 
    d0:hexd (d1:hexd (d2:hexd (d3:hexd (d4:hexd d5:hexd?)?)?)?)?
{
    return [d0, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5].join("");
}
hexd "hexadecimal digit" =
    [0-9a-fA-F]

cssFunctional "pseudo-selector or functional selector" =
    ":" cssIdentifier ( "(" cssArg ")" )?

cssAttrExpr "attribute selector" =
    "[" cssIdentifier (
        [|~\*^$]? "=" (cssIdentifier / quotedString)
    )? "]"

quotedString "quoted string" = 
    "'" (escapedChar / [^\'])* "'"
  / '"' (escapedChar / [^\"])* '"'

cssArg "functional selector argument" = 
    anpbOddEven / uint / jqSelector

anpbOddEven "'an+b' expression, 'odd',  'even', or integer" = 
    [-\+]? uint? [nN] (ws* [-\+] ws* uint)? 
  / [-\+] uint 
  / "even"
  / "odd"

uint "unsigned integer" = [1-9][0-9]* / "0"
```

Answer (score 2):

I can only review the JS part, [I am not sure that grammar reviews are part of CR](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1345/14625).

**collapse**

- `else` branches after a `return` do not make sense.
- I would propose `map`/`join` instead of `reduce`/`concat`

Something likes this:

```
function collapse(stuff) {
    if (typeof stuff === "string")
        return stuff;
    if (stuff instanceof Array) 
        return stuff.map(function ( value ) {
          return collapse( value );
        }).join("");
    return "";
}
```

**trimWs**

The function does not match the comment, and I cannot see what it is supposed to do. You need a better function name, a better parameter name and a proper comment explaining what it does and how it is used.

**Update**

```
trimWs( "abc" ) -> Returns " "
trimWs( "  " ) -> Returns " "
trimWs( " " ) -> Returns " "
trimWs( "\t" ) -> Returns " "
trimWs( "" ) -> Returns ""
trimWs( "   abc   " ) -> Returns " "
If this function were trimming, it would return "abc" for the last call
```

Basically it returns a space except for provided empty strings and empty arrays. The code could very well be:

```
function reduceToSingleSpace( x ) {
  return ( !x || ( x && x instanceof Array && !x.length ) )?"":" ";
}
```

Comment: `trimWs` = `trim` `W`hite `s`pace.  It determines if any white space is `present` by examining its parameter and returns a single space or nothing.  In CSS, `a#foo p.bar` is the same as `a#foo                 p.bar` but not the same as `a#foop.bar`.  Can't get rid of the spaces altogether, but there's no point in holding onto more than one.  Can you give me an example of a more appropriate name?  Good call on map/join, will do, thanks.

Comment: In the above comment, the second `a#foo p.bar` was supposed to have many spaces.  Not sure where they went.  Ironically, that's exactly what the function does - get rid of extraneous white space.

Comment: Updated the answer, not too excited by `reduceToSingleSpace`, but that's the best I could come up with so far.

Comment: `trimWs(" abc ")` is where the PEG is important; `trimWs` is only called to process the `cws` (for `c`ollapsed `w`hite `s`pace) token.  I suppose I should probably both rename `collapse` to `serialize` (to avoid confusion about the two senses of the word collapse) and move the body of `trimWs` to be an anonymous function in the `cws` token?  What do you think?

Comment: It sounds better than what you have now or what I proposed.

Comment: Alright, updating with revision, and waiting for either feedback on the PEG or a determination that it's OT for accept.